# My system only see 8Gb instead of 12Gb memory, can you help me please?

Tags: ram, remapping

Help me please!
I have a MSI H55M-P31 motherboard with an i7 870 @ 2.93 GHz processor.
Both of them supports memory up to 16Gb.
I have installed 2x4Gb and 2x2Gb.
My system only see 8Gb total, the 2x4Gb.

My output for "sudo dmidecode -t 16":

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4
```

My output for "sudo lshw -class memory":

```
*-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: V1.3
       date: 12/21/2009
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       capabilities: isa pci pnp upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: internal write-through instruction
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: internal write-through unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 2a
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 12GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous
          product: ModulePartNumber00
          vendor: Manufacturer00
          physical id: 0
          serial: SerNum00
          slot: DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous
          product: ModulePartNumber01
          vendor: Manufacturer01
          physical id: 1
          serial: SerNum01
          slot: DIMM2
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous
          product: ModulePartNumber02
          vendor: Manufacturer02
          physical id: 2
          serial: SerNum02
          slot: DIMM3
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous
          product: ModulePartNumber03
          vendor: Manufacturer03
          physical id: 3
          serial: SerNum03
          slot: DIMM4
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
```

How could I get to use all 12Gb? Is there a way to remap my memory? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If your BIOS show 8GB as well, it is not related to Ubuntu. It means that this RAM configuration is not supported. Refer to the MB manual or contact the MB support.

Comment: What does `free -h` show?

Comment: this:$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       2.0Gi       4.4Gi       244Mi       1.4Gi       5.2Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi

Comment: You probably already know this: you probably have RAM slots which need to be 'paired' with identical SIMMs in the pair. The pairs can be identified by numbers on the MB and/or colour of the slot. You probably want the larger SIMMs in the first slot pair. Sometimes you need to 're-seat' your SIMMs to get them working. As @Pilot6 says, check your MB manual.

Comment: If I put them paired, still it only sees 6Gb meaning, it sees the first two slots. Previously I had the 2x2Gb in paired slots and it`s been working fine. Now I can use only the 1st 2 slots, nothing is seen in the pairs. If I only put ram in the 3rd and/or 4th slots, bios messages me beeping "bad memory". In some variations it keeps restarting to find the right settings, til it starts using the 1st two slots. Still, I can see the details of the rams in bios where I can see 12Gb. In the OS, I can see 8Gb,in terminal I get to see all the slots, all the rams, but the capacity is shown maximum 8Gb.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I suspect that my motherboard is damaged under the processor, can`t think of anything else. Using it with 8Gb atm.

Comment: @makako Please see Update #2 in my answer. Report back. Did you ever contact MSI Support?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

You have one (or more) of these five issues...

1. Your BIOS is too old
2. You have incorrect spec DIMM sticks
3. You have the memory DIMMS installed into the incorrect slots
4. You may need to have similar DIMMS in all four slots
5. You have a defective motherboard

**BIOS**

MSI H55M-P31

You have BIOS version: V1.3, dated: 12/21/2009. BIOS version 1.A is available [here](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/H55MP31#down-bios).

[image]

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

See https://storage-asset.msi.com/files/pdf/How_to_flash_the_BIOS.pdf and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRyFMf0D9Lc for help.

**Memory**

Here is a page from the motherboard User Manual:

[image]

Your 4G DIMMS should be installed into slots DIMM1 and DIMM3.

Your 2G DImms should be installed into slots DIMM2 and DIMM4.

If that doesn't solve your problem, you'll have to get 4G DIMMS similar to the DIMMS installed in DIMM1 and DIMM3, and replace the 2G DIMMS. See the note below...

[image]

**Update #1:**

Have done items #1 and #3/4 and the problem persists. Suggest contacting MSI Support.

**Update #2:**

Install 4x4G RAM DIMMs, then,

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118702/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-my-system-only-see-8gb-instead-of-12gb-memory).